# Find if an item exists in a list using regex pattern

Tags: c#, regex, list

I've a list of files with timestamp appended to it.I Also have another list which contains regex patterns. I wanted to verify all patterns in 'refFiles' exists in 'files' for not.

Below is the samples files,

```
List<string> files = new List<string>();
files.Add("AB_DBER_2016101194814.txt");
files.Add("AB_EBER_2016101194815.txt");
files.Add("AB_FBER_2016101194811.txt");
```

This is the reference patterns:

```
List<string> refFiles = new List<string>();
refFiles.Add("AB_DBER_[0-9]{13,13}.txt");
refFiles.Add("AB_EBER_[0-9]{13,13}.txt");
refFiles.Add("AB_FBER_[0-9]{13,13}.txt");
```

I wanted to do something like:

```
 foreach (var file in refFiles )
 {
   //if file has a match in files then I need to do some code
 }
```

I wanted to know how I can find the regex pattern in second list to verify that matching patern exists in first list.

Comment: what's the problem exactly? you don't know how to do the regex? or?

Comment: I wanted to know how I can find the regex pattern in second list to verify that matching patern exists in first list,

Comment: `[0-9]{13,13}` => `[0-9]{13}` => `\d{13}`

Comment: And my guess is that you should be escaping that period before the extension `\\.txt` (escaped backslash since not a verbatim string)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Could you tell me how the correct regex swhould be to match the text AB_DBER_2016101194814.txt ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a general approach, with which [you can fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HDP4vL).

Note the change to your regex. It uses `\.` instead of `.` inside a literal `@` string; that will match a period [instead of the wildcard character class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#character_classes).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> files = new List<string>();
        files.Add("AB_DBER_2016101194814.txt");
        files.Add("AB_EBER_2016101194815.txt");
        files.Add("AB_FBER_2016101194811.txt");

        // the following will not match
        files.Add("AB_FBER_20161011948111txt");
        files.Add("This_Does_Not_Match.txt");

        List<string> refFiles = new List<string>();
        refFiles.Add(@"AB_DBER_[0-9]{13,13}\.txt");
        refFiles.Add(@"AB_EBER_[0-9]{13,13}\.txt");
        refFiles.Add(@"AB_FBER_[0-9]{13,13}\.txt");
        foreach (var pattern in refFiles)
        {
            var regex = new Regex(pattern);
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (regex.IsMatch(file))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(file);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also [use LINQ](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ay9cQK):

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
    if (refFiles.Any(pattern => Regex.IsMatch(file, pattern)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file);
    }
}
```

In both cases, this is the output:

```
AB_DBER_2016101194814.txt
AB_EBER_2016101194815.txt
AB_FBER_2016101194811.txt
```

Comment: Is it possible to avoid the second foreach?  like if it's not regular expression then I can find in the first foeach using list.contains ?

Comment: @blue I do not know what you mean by "like if it's not regular expression..." In any case, I added an alternative with LINQ, which hides the second loop within `Any`.

Comment: Should probably escape those periods otherwise "AB_DBER_2016101194814txt" (no file extension and incorrectly named) would also match

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Nice catch. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me

```
        var files = new List<string>
        {
            "AB_DBER_2016101194814.txt",
            "AB_EBER_2016101194815.txt",
            "AB_FBER_2016101194811.txt"
        };

        var refFiles = new List<string>
        {
            "AB_DBER_[0-9]{13,13}.txt",
            "AB_EBER_[0-9]{13,13}.txt",
            "AB_FBER_[0-9]{13,13}.txt"
        };

        foreach (var patternFile in refFiles)
        {
            var regularExp = new Regex(patternFile);
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (regularExp.IsMatch(file))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(file);
                }
            }
        }
```